# How can i fetch logged in users email id in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can I get logged in users **email** id in dialogflow and send it to webhook.
I am integrating it with google assistant.

Comment: Can you update your question with some more information? What integrations are you using? How is the user logging in?

Answer (score 1):

You can get user's email by asking them to link their google account with your agent.
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in